# Avoid creating start menu shortcuts in Basic MSI project

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, shortcut

I have Basic MSI setup created with InstallShield 2015.
The setup install files and creates shortcuts on desktop and start menu folder.
I want to enable the user to select if he want to create shortcuts or not so is there a property I can set so shortcuts on start menu folder will not be created ?

Currently the components include files and the shortcuts on start menu ( while shortcuts on desktop are on separate component with a condition ) 
so if I want to use a condition I will need to split each component to files and start menu shortcuts and I want to avoid it,
I also can’t disable CreateShortcuts CA since it that case also the desktop shortcuts will not be created.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's wrong with just deleting the shortcut if anyway you don't want it to appear? "System Configuration" -> "Shortcuts" ->"Start Menu"; find shortcut you don't want and delete it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to enable the user option to choose if he want to create the shortcuts or not.

Comment: MSI doesn't offer what you ask for. If you want to condition the shortcut, you have to condition the component that contains it. Assuming you want the files regardless, this means they will have to be in separate components.